# Access violation occurred in glfwSwapBuffers()

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm making an OpenGL program using version 4.6, but when I wrote the texture code and ran the program, the following error occurred in glfwSwapBuffers():
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFCCD631970 (nvoglv64.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

Here's my code :

```
#include"shader.h"
#include"texture.h"

#include<glad/glad.h>
#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    
    if (glfwInit() == GLFW_FALSE) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 800, "What a TD", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (gladLoadGL() != 1) {
        std::cout << "Failed to load GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, 1280, 800);

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    GLuint indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0
    };

    GLuint vbo, vao, ebo;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
    
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    
    texture tex0("planks.png", 0);
    
    shader Shader("default.vs", "default.fs");
    
    //main loop
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        Shader.use();
        tex0.active();
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(indices) / sizeof(GLuint), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window); // Access violation
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    ...
}
```

vertex shader :

```
#version 460 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 Color;
out vec2 texCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0f);
    Color = aColor;
    texCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

fragment shader :

```
#version 460 core

in vec3 Color;
in vec2 texCoord;

out vec4 fragColor;

uniform sampler2D tex0;

void main() {
    fragColor = texture(tex0, texCoord);
}
```

texture.h :

```
#ifndef GL_TEXTURE_H
#define GL_TEXTURE_H

#include<glad/glad.h>
#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include<stb/stb_image.h> //STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION defined in other file

#include<iostream>

class texture {
private:
    GLuint ID;
    GLuint unit;
public:
    texture(const char* image, GLuint unit)  {
        stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);

        this->unit = unit;

        glGenTextures(1, &ID);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ID);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        int width, height, channels;
        unsigned char* data = stbi_load(image, &width, &height, &channels, 0);
        if (data) {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << image << " : " << "Failed to load image" << std::endl;
        }
    
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    
        stbi_image_free(data);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }

    void active() {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ID);
    }
};

#endif
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: `0x0000000000000000` is a null pointer

Comment: Have you enabled [Debug Output](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Debug_Output)? That will probably give you a good hint as to what was null in the ICD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Index Buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers) (`ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`) binding is stored within the [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers). When `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO)` is called the element buffer object ID is stored in the currently bound Vertex Array Object.
Calling `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);` when the VAO is bound breaks that binding and the index buffer is no longer bound to the VAO. Remove this line of code, you don't need it at all.

<s>`glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);`</s>

```cpp
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Unlike to the [Index Buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers), the [Vertex Buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) binding (`ARRAY_BUFFER`) is a global state.
Each attribute which is stated in the VAOs state vector may refer to a different `ARRAY_BUFFER`. When [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is called the buffer which is currently bound to the target `ARRAY_BUFFER`, is associated to the specified attribute index and the ID of the object is stored in the state vector of the currently bound VAO. Therefore there is no problem calling  `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);`